# AWS Cloudwatch: How to add the instance name / custom fields to the log?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We currently have multiple cloudwatch log streams per ec2 instance. This is horrible to debug; queries for "ERROR XY" across all instances would involve either digging into each log stream (time consuming) or using aws cli (time consuming queries).

I would prefer to have a log stream combining the log data of all instances of a specific type, let's say all "webserver" instances log their "apache2" log data to one central stream and "php" log data to another central stream.

Obviously, I still want to be able to figure out which log entry stems from which instance - as I would be with central logging via syslogd.

How can I add the custom field "instance id" to the logs in cloudwatch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to organize logs in CloudWatch Logs is as follows:

- The log group represents the log type. For example: webserver/prod.
- The log stream represents the instance id (i.e. the source).

For querying, I highly recommend using the [Insights](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-insights-fast-interactive-log-analytics/) feature (I helped build it when I worked @ AWS). The log stream name will be available with each log record as a special `@logStream` field.

You can query across all instances like this:

```
filter @message like /ERROR XY/
```

Or inside one instance like this:

```
filter @message like /ERROR XY/ and @logStream = "instance_id"
```